# Scala how to match two dfs if mathes then update the key in first df and select all columns from required df

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have data in two dataframes:

selectedPersonDF:

```
ID    key  Name
1          lak
2          Mouny   
3          kkk
4          nnn
5          hhh
```

selectedDetailsDF:

```
first  second third  key
--------------------------
1       9       9    777
9       8       8    878
8       10      10   765
10      12      19   909
11      2       20   708

val columnsToCheck = selectedDetailsDF.columns.toSet - "key" toList

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val tempSelectedDetailsDF = selectedDetailsDF.select(array(columnsToCheck.map(col): _*).as("array"), col("key").as("key2"))



val arrayContains = udf((array: collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String], value: String) => array.contains(value))

val finalDF = selectedPersonDF.join(tempSelectedDetailsDF, arrayContains($"array", $"ID"), "left")
  .select($"ID", $"key2".as("key"))
  .na.fill("")
```

Getting output as below,

```
+---+---+
|ID |key|
+---+---+
|1  |777|
|2  |708|
|3  |   |
|4  |   |
|5  |   |
+---+---+
```

expecting: 
i want to show all my columns from selectedPersonDF I have to match the selectedPersonDF id column with selectedDetailsDF all the columns(First, Second, Third) if any of the column data matches with persons id then we have to take the key value from selectedDetailsDF and have to update in selectedPersonDF key column

```
ID    key  Name
1     777  lak
2     708  Mouny   
3          kkk
4          nnn
5          hhh
```

Please help me anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select `Name` column as well

```
val finalDF = selectedPersonDF.join(tempSelectedDetailsDF, arrayContains($"array", $"ID"), "left")
  .select($"ID", $"key", $"Name")
  .na.fill("")
```

and you should be fine

If there are more columns in `selectedPersonDF` and you want to `select` all of them as

```
val columnsToSelect = selectedPersonDF.columns
val finalDF = selectedPersonDF.join(tempSelectedDetailsDF, arrayContains($"array", $"ID"), "left")
  .select(columnToSelect.map(col): _*)
  .na.fill("")
```

Comment: i tried first one it is working but i have more column to select all of them so i went second one i got error 'key' is ambiguous, could be: key#1, key#104.;

Comment: I have updated the answer please check :) it was due to duplicate `key` column when you used alias. now it should work

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the `UDF`, I suggest you use built-in functions which helps in optimization,

You can use a combination of multiple keys to join and get the result as below

```
  val joinCondition = df1("ID") === selectedDetailsDF("A") ||
    df1("ID") === selectedDetailsDF("B") ||
    df1("ID") === selectedDetailsDF("C")

  val df2 = df1.drop("key")
    .join(selectedDetailsDF, joinCondition, "left")
    .drop("A", "B", "c")
    .withColumnRenamed("D", "key")
    .na.fill("")
```

I hope this is more optimized rather than using udf. I hope this helps you.